# how to create a new bundle for Juju 2.0 and Ubuntu 16.04Lts

Tags: juju

I saw that are present few bundle on Juju 2.0 store for environment with Ubuntu 16.04 Lts installed on nodes. 
I'd like to create a new one and deploy it on my lab, a bumble like Nginx with MariaDB and haproxy.

Someone can suggest the procedure to realise that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a bundle:

- Open up your model in the GUI using the command `juju gui --show-credentials` which will open up a new browser window and output your credentials to the console.
- Click the button in the top left of the GUI which looks like an arrow coming out of a box.
- The downloaded file will be a bundle file representing your model. Feel free to manually edit this file to many any valid changes.
- You will then be able to deploy this bundle via the Juju CLI or by importing it back into the GUI in a new model.

Comment: if a charm for 16.04 is not available, how do I've to build it? ex. Nginx is present only for Trusty if I want to create one for Xenial...thanks